# Composition factor multiplicities of parabolic Verma module

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-algebras

As a follow up question of this [post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/262523/references-and-enlightenment-for-kazhdan-lusztig-composition-factor-multipliciti).

Let $M_I(\eta)$ be the parabolic Verma module with weight $\eta$ and $L(\eta)$ is its unique simple quotient.

> For $\lambda,\mu\in\Lambda_I^+$, can we express $[M_I(\lambda):L(\mu)]$ in terms of Kazhdan-Lusztig polynomials? If this can be done, I hope to see the explicit formula.
>
> P.S. $\lambda$ can be singular or non-integral.

On p.193 of **Representations of Semisimple Lie Algebras in the BGG Category $\mathcal{O}$.**[image]

> What is the current state of the question:
> **When is $[M_I(\lambda):L(\mu)]\neq 0$?** Is it still open or anyone knows the answer but no one bother to write it out?